# get and set attribute value for element in awesomium in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, attributes, getelementbyid, awesomium

i want to get element by id and then get attribute and etc....

in web browser i use from this code :

```
                HtmlElement element = wb.Document.Body.Document.GetElementById("dnn_ctr730_ViewTMUrbanFileStatusFromWebService_fb_Captcha_CaptchaImageUP");
                if (element != null)
                {
                    string link = element.GetAttribute("src");
```

but in awesomium  how can i do this ?

and also when i want to set value to element in web browser using from this code :

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("txtFileNo").SetAttribute("Value", "12345");
wb.Document.GetElementById("BTN").InvokeMember("click");
```

but i don't know how can i do this in awesomium  ....

i found this code for set value :

```
        dynamic document = (JSObject)webctrl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
        if (document == null)
            return "";
        using (document)
        {
            dynamic elem = document.getElementById("txt1");

            if (elem == null)
                return "";

            using (elem)
                elem.value = "test";
```

but i don't know how to invoke Click and also how to get attribute value...

anye one can help me ..?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [jQuery's attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [jQuery's trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
webctrl.ExecuteJavascript("$(#txtFileNo).attr('value', '12345');");
webctrl.ExecuteJavascript("$(#BTN).trigger('click');");
```

Since you are targeting a single browser, you could use plain old Javascript for this against the Chromium DOM.  But, I find [jQuery's trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to be much easier to use than the alternative.

Comment: thanks for your info , all good but only submit code `"$(BTN).trigger('click');"` not work for me ! do you can give me more solution ?kind regards

Comment: :also i use from these code : `dynamic element = (JSObject)webctrl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('btn')");
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.Invoke("click");
                element.Invoke("submit");
            }`  but not work too......

Comment: :OPS WTF ! :( I don't use from correct ElementById !!! OMG ! i used from textbox ElementById for BTN ! ....Thanks for your time ... OMG fffff ! Thanks kind regards :)